# ¿Cómo puedo cargar los datos de un JSON que se encuentran en una url y los deseo pasar a un array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Para ahora para obtener la información, debo hacer un llamado AJAX, por ejemplo  a la siguiente URL: https://s3.amazonaws.com/countries/countries.json.

Y debo pasare esos datos a un array al cual le voy hacer un proceso para desplegarlos en una página HTML.

Este es mi código ya con las modificaciones que me indicaron, pero  al parecer no reconoce el $.getJSON:

El error que genera es: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $

Esta es la estructura del JSON:

0
code    "CO"
name    "Colombia"
flag_url    "https://s3.amazonaws.com/makeitreal/co.gif"

// escribe tu código acá
$(document).ready(function(){
    var countries = $.getJSON("https://s3.amazonaws.com/makeitreal/countries.json");
    $('button').click(function(){
        cargarTabla();
        $('button').hide();
    });

```
function cargarTabla(){
    var tabla = "";
    tabla+= "<table>";
    tabla+= "<tr>" 
    tabla+= "<th>Flag</th>"
    tabla+= "<th>Code</th>"
    tabla+= "<th>Name</th>"
    tabla+="</tr>";
  for (var i = 0; i < countries.responseJSON.length; i++) {
        tabla+="<tr>";
        tabla+="<td>" + "<img src=" + countries[i].flag_url + ">" + "</td>";
        tabla+="<td>" + countries[i].code + "</td>";
        tabla+="<td>" + countries[i].name + "</td>";
        tabla+="</tr>";
    }   
    tabla+= "</table>";
    $('.wrapper').append(tabla);
}
```

});

Comment: Antes los leía desde  JSON que pasaba a un array:

Comment: ¿En qué lenguaje? Deberías etiquetar la pregunta con el lenguaje... Y ¿Qué intentaste?

Comment: @Mariano, no estoy trabajando con ningún lenguaje, solo necesito leer el JSON y mostrarlo en una página HTML.

Comment: @Mariano, puedo hacer esto?
var countries = $.getJSON("https://s3.amazonaws.com/makeitreal/countries.json");

Comment: Ese lenguaje se llama JavaScript

Comment: podrias mostrar la información con la que se llena `countries`?, o por lo menos sus estructura y algunos datos inventados.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tal como lo veo tienes 2 opciones

Llena `countries` con el `json` que devuelve la consulta

```
var countries;
$.getJSON("https://s3.amazonaws.com/makeitreal/countries.json", function (data){
     countries = data;//data devuelve el objeto json
});
```

Como lo tienes hecho pero recorrer `countries.responseJSON`

```
var countries = $.getJSON("https://s3.amazonaws.com/makeitreal/countries.json");
for (var i = 0; i < countries.responseJSON.length; i++) {
}
```

**EDITO:**

Para el error

> Can't find variable: $

Tienes agregado `Jquery` en tu página?
Si no es así, agrega el siguiente `script`.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

PD:Deberías contemplar el cambiar la formulación de la pregunta ya que el problema real no tiene mucho que ver con la pregunta actual

Answer (score 0):

Totalmente de acuerdo con el compañero anterior, ademas tu código falla por que la variable countries que declaras, dentro de la función cargar tabla no existe por que es local al ready, además en el bucle de la función cargarTabla no estás extrayendo correctamente los valores de cada item, teniendo en cuenta que hayas incluido jquery y demás, este es tu código con un par de cambios y a mi me funciona.

```
    function cargarTabla(countries){
        var tabla = "";
        tabla+= "<table>";
        tabla+= "<tr>" 
        tabla+= "<th>Flag</th>"
        tabla+= "<th>Code</th>"
        tabla+= "<th>Name</th>"
        tabla+="</tr>";

        for (var i = 0; i < countries.responseJSON.length; i++) {
            tabla+="<tr>";
            tabla+="<td>" + "<img src=" + countries.responseJSON[i].flag_url + ">" + "</td>";
            tabla+="<td>" + countries.responseJSON[i].code + "</td>";
            tabla+="<td>" + countries.responseJSON[i].name + "</td>";
            tabla+="</tr>";
         }   
        tabla+= "</table>";
        $('.wrapper').append(tabla);
   }

  $(document).ready(function(){ 
      var countries = $.getJSON("https://s3.amazonaws.com/makeitreal/countries.json"); 
      $('button').on("click",function(e){
            cargarTabla(countries); 
            $('button').hide(); 
      });
  });
```

Espero que te sirva, un saludo

Comment: funcionó correctamente sus indicaciones, excelente aporte, debido a que la plataforma que evalúa la respuesta no la reconocía como válida debí hacer las correcciones que aparecen en mi respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Aunque la respuesta de  @Jaimito Pago y @elfinti funcionarion; como es una plataforma la que evalúa la solución, genereba un error, debí manejar mediante un callback la carga de los datos y no llevarlos a una variable, quedando de esta manera:

```
function cargarTabla(countries){
   var tabla = "";
   tabla+= "<table>";
   tabla+= "<tr>" 
   tabla+= "<th>Flag</th>"
   tabla+= "<th>Code</th>"
   tabla+= "<th>Name</th>"
   tabla+="</tr>";

  for (var i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
    tabla+="<tr>";
    tabla+="<td>" + "<img src=" + countries[i].flag_url + ">" + "</td>";
    tabla+="<td>" + countries[i].code + "</td>";
    tabla+="<td>" + countries[i].name + "</td>";
    tabla+="</tr>";
    }   
    tabla+= "</table>";
    $('.wrapper').append(tabla);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
     $('button').on("click",function(e){
         $.getJSON("https://s3.amazonaws.com/makeitreal/countries.json",          function(data) {
          cargarTabla(data);
          $('button').hide();
         });
     });
 });
```